# Does editing a form update the case property?

Tags: commcare

Per the CommCare help site (https://wiki.commcarehq.org/display/commcarepublic/Edit+Form+Submissions), it seems like if I edit a form in the edit form submission function and edit a question that updates a case property, the case property will be updated by this edited form (see the bullet from the help site below):

Case management is supported. Any updates to the case that are made will be applied in the order the submission was originally received in. This means that if you change question that updates a case property, and that property was changed by a form that was submitted after the one you are editing, that change should not be reflected in the final case state.

I want to confirm that if there are no other changes to the particular case property that is updated by the edited question in the form, that the change will be reflected.

Answer (score 1):

> This means that if you change a question that updates a case property, and that property was changed by a form that was submitted after the one you are editing, that change should not be reflected in the final case state.

This is correct.

> I want to confirm that if there are no other changes to the particular case property that is updated by the edited question in the form, that the change will be reflected.

This is also correct. If the form you are editing is the last form to touch a case property then that case property change will be reflected in the current case.